# How can set my Android Project SDK for particular project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

**How can do set my project SDK for particular project**
I just want to set particular Android SDK for particular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Studio

Go to

File -> project Structure into Project Structure
Left -> SDK Location
SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

Comment: it does not work for me.